# Drawing an image in javascript won't work when vars are global

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

Hey I want to draw multiple images, one a canvas background, two a player that can move on top of that canvas.  Here is my question: When I put the var canvas and canvas properties globally it doesn't work. But when I put it back in the img.onload function it works!!! Why is this and what options do I have?

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("Canvas");
 canvas.width = 500;     
 canvas.height = 500;
 var g = canvas.getContext("2d");

var img = new Image();   
img.src = "Images/Grass Texture.png";

var player1 = new Image();   
player1.src = "Images/Players/Mignolet.png";

var player2 = new Image();   
player2.src = "Images/Players/De Gea.png";

var football = new Image();   
football.src = "Images/Football/Football.png";

img.onload = function()
{
   /* The rest of the code draws onto the graphics context */
   g.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
   g.drawImage(img,1200, 1200, 1200, 1200); 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's important to understand that image loading is asynchronous. That means while your image is loading the code will continue despite.

If the browser is not able to load and decode the images in time there won't be any images to draw.

Even when you use the `onload` handler (which is necessary) you need to think about the asynchronous nature in the rest of the code - perhaps the code continues to other parts which will fail due to dependency on the images.

You can collect image loading like this:

```
...

/// if you have many images an array could be considered    
var img = new Image();   
var player1 = new Image();   
var player2 = new Image();   
var football = new Image();   

/// number of images to load
var count = 4;

/// now share a load handler
img.onload      = loadHandler;
player1.onload  = loadHandler;
player2.onload  = loadHandler;
football.onload = loadHandler;

/// set sources to start loading
img.src      = "Images/Grass Texture.png";
player1.src  = "Images/Players/Mignolet.png";
player2.src  = "Images/Players/De Gea.png";
football.src = "Images/Football/Football.png";

function loadHandler() {

    /// decrement the counter
    count--;

    /// when 0 all images has loaded
    if (count === 0) startGame();
}
```

When all images has loaded the script will continue to `startGame()` which is also where you need to continue your game from:

```
function startGame() {
    ...
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    g.drawImage(img,1200, 1200, 1200, 1200); 

    /// Important! continue your code from here
    nextStep();
}
```

So after invoking image loading by setting the sources your script does not call any other steps until `startGame()` is called.

Now, the loading can fail for various reasons. If you don't handle errors your game might just stop and you won't know why. During development you should of course always check the console for errors (see console, network etc. if any errors occur) but for a user this won't help much.

You should always add an error handler mechanism to the images as well. You can do this by using the `onerror` and `onabort` handlers - after setting the `onload` handler:

```
var hasErrors    = false;

img.onerror      = errorHandler;
player1.onerror  = errorHandler;
player2.onerror  = errorHandler;
football.onerror = errorHandler;

img.onabort      = errorHandler;  /// or use a separate abort handler
player1.onabort  = errorHandler;
player2.onabort  = errorHandler;
football.onabort = errorHandler;
```

In the error handler you can notify the user, or use a fallback, or anything that can possible solve the situation:

```
function errorHandler(err) {

    /// set error flag
    hasErrors = true;

    /// notify user, post an error message etc. something..
    console.log('Could not load image:', this.src, err);

    /// call loadHandler() from here to decrement counter and
    /// handle situation when all images has reported in for duty (or not)
    loadHandler();
}
```

And then modify the `loadHandler` to be error aware (just an alert here, but replace with something more useful):

```
function loadHandler() {

    /// decrement the counter
    count--;

    /// when 0 all images has loaded
    if (count === 0) {
        if (hasErrors) {
            alert('Sorry mate! Error during image loading');
            return;
        }
        startGame();
    }
}
```

That being said, you can also do this by using an image loader that can handle all the setup and events (loading, errors, progress etc.) for you. These are made, incl. my own if I may, [YAIL loader](https://github.com/AbdiasSoftware/YAIL-imageLoader-for-JavaScript) (and there are others), for the purpose of saving developers from a lot of problems and headache - and they are free. Something to consider..

Hope this helps!